# Filling 2D array with spaces C

Tags: c

I have a string

```
char str[] = "12313b/122a34679/12a345679/12a345679/12a345678/12a345978/12a345879/12a385679/18a345679";
```

and I have to insert it into a two-dimensional array called `board`.

So like for a row I have got 12313b, second 122a34679.

`a` = one space, `b` = two spaces, `c` = three space etc..

And if for string like 12313b is less that 9, I have to fill the board with spaces.

for example: 12313b in board 12313" "" "" "" "

First two become spaces, because `b` is equal to 2 spaces, and last two is because I have to fill.

```
void createBoard(char board[][SIZE*SIZE],char str[]){
int place = 0;
char *token = strtok(str, "/");
char *array[SIZE*SIZE];
while (token != NULL) {
    array[place++] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
for (int num = 0; num <SIZE*SIZE ; num++) {//COUNT DIGITS
    int count = strlen(array[num]);
    for (int place = 0; place < strlen(array[num]); ++place) {
        if (array[num][place] >= 'a' && array[num][place] <= 'a' + SIZE * SIZE - 1) {
            int spaces = array[num][place] - 'a' + 1;
            count += spaces - 1;
        }
    }
    if (count > SIZE * SIZE)
        printf("Error\n");
    else {
        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE * SIZE; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < SIZE * SIZE;) {
                if (array[row][column] >= 'a' && array[row][column] <= 'a' + SIZE * SIZE - 1) {
                    int spaces = (array[row][column]) - 'a' + 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i) {
                        board[row][column] = ' ';
                        column++;
                    }
                } else {
                    board[row][column] = array[row][column];
                    column++;
                }
                if (count < SIZE * SIZE) {
                    for (int empty = count; empty < SIZE * SIZE; ++empty) {
                        board[row][empty] = '-';
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this output, which is wrong:

[image]

The `|` is inserted by me

Comment: Your question is absolutely incomprehensible. You keep talking about spaces, but there are none. You will have to work on your problem description if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `SIZE*SIZE` elements. But what if the tokenization loop doesn't initialize all those elements? Then the remaining elements will be left *uninitialized* with *indeterminate* values. Using these uninitialized elements in almost any way will lead to *undefined behavior*.

In further loops you can't use `SIZE*SIZE` as the limit, you must use `place` as that is the actual count on the number of elements in the array.

That of course means you can't shadow the variable `place` in other places. Or create a new `count` or similarly named variable to keep the size.

Furthermore you use `SIZE*SIZE` as the length of each string inside the array `array`, which might be longer (or shorter) than the actual length of the string.

All in all, plenty of chances to go out of bounds of strings and arrays, leading to the already mentioned undefined behavior.

Comment: It’s taking chars from array [1]
How is that happening

Comment: @MahmudHassan Have you tried to *debug* your code?